# Not be able to set up VM Insight in VMSS using AMA from portal

Tags: azure, azure-vm-scale-set

-Incident
After setting up VM Insight to be enabled, I get the page to enable it and cannot see the logs.so I can not confirm Insight & logs after wating more than 10 minuites
By enablingI have confirmed that the data collection rules for VMSS have been created.
In addition, I have confirmed that AMA and DAL are installed as Extensions.

-My reference to set up
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/vm/vminsights-overview?toc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fja-jp%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-machine-scale-sets%2Ftoc.json&bc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fja-jp%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/vm/vminsights-enable-portal

enabling Insights with AMA
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uniTx.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYYTQ.png)

I confirmed that deployment succeeded
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMgLz.png)
I also confirmed that Data collection rule was configured
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCF8O.png)

but, Insight page of VMSS is still not enabled.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrBFZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have followed the steps below to resolve the issue:

Click on Azure Monitor, go to the overview, and check if Azure Monitor for VMSS is enabled.

[image]

[image]

Navigate to the data source resource and go to the configuration section. Under data sources, add the **Linux Syslog** and **Performance** counters as shown in the screenshots below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Next, upgrade the VMSS image and ensure that the latest image is being used. Refer to the screenshots provided:

[image]

[image]

Next, navigate to the insights page under the monitoring session in VMSS and check the status. Refer to the screenshots below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your thoughtful response! I could solve my problem not to enabling Insight. I can also confirm log using query. (Actually, the fact that I can't see the logs is what prompted this inquiry.)